# django-formtools, saving data between form steps

Tags: django, django-formtools

I am trying to create a multi-step form wizard using [django-formtools](https://github.com/jazzband/django-formtools). I have a main model called `Report` and several ModelForms as follows:

```
class ReportFormP1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = [
            'company',
            'address_line_1',
            'address_line_2',
            'responsible_person',
            'person_consulted',
            'assessor_name',
            'previous_assessment_date',
            'review_date',
        ]


# section 1
class ReportFormP2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = [
            "premise_num_floors",
            "premise_floor_area",
            "premise_occupancy",
            "premise_occupancy_comments",
        ]
```

in my views, I have created the following view:

class ReportWizardView(SessionWizardView):
template_name = 'reporting/report_create2.html'
form_list = [ReportFormP1, ReportFormP2]

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    return render(self.request, 'done.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
    })
```

And my relevant template looks as follows:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!-- templates/home.html -->
{% load socialaccount %}

{% block title %}Create a report{% endblock title %}

{% block extra_css %}
    {{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock extra_css %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Create a report</h1>

    <p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
    
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ wizard.management_form }}

        {% if wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
            {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            {{ wizard.form|crispy }}
        {% endif %}

        <div class="text-center">
            {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}" formnovalidate>{% trans "first step" %}</button>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}" formnovalidate>{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
            {% endif %}
            {% if wizard.steps.next %}
                <button class="btn  btn-lg btn-primary" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.next }}">{% trans "next step" %}</button>
            {% endif %}

            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create report">

        </div>

    </form>

    <hr>
    <hr>
    
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

My urls.py look as follows:

```
    path('create_report2', ReportWizardView.as_view(), name="report_create2"),
```

My problem is that the form steps are not being saved when I click on `next`, and then `previous` (the form is valid). Bellow is an example

First form loaded:

[image: 8e66r.png]
<sub>(source: [imge.to](https://b.imge.to/2019/08/16/8e66r.png))</sub>

After clicking on 'next':

[image: 8eQnO.png]
<sub>(source: [imge.to](https://b.imge.to/2019/08/16/8eQnO.png))</sub>

Now when i click on 'previous', everything is gone:

[image: 8eMqq.png]
<sub>(source: [imge.to](https://b.imge.to/2019/08/16/8eMqq.png))</sub>

I wonder what I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

As per Formtools documentation you need to Enable Session.

https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.SessionWizardView